# Blocked Processes

Tags: process, operating-system

As far as I know, some conditions must be validated so that a process continue to run. If they are not confirmed, the processor blocks that process not to waste time. After these conditions are validated, the process enter into `ready state`.

However, I faced a sentence like this in the book "Modern Operating Systems Andrew Tanenbaum": `There are two types of processes which are system processes and user processes. If processor takes a disk interrupt when it executes a user application, the system makes a decision to stop running the current process, and starts to run disk process. In this case, application process is kept in blocked state. After the disk is read or anything is written on the disk, the process waiting for it is unblocked.`

I know that a process is blocked in only the situation that a requirement or a condition is not validated. However, I suppose this sentence try to say that disk process has higher precedence, that's why application process is blocked. Is the precedence a factor to block any process ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing makes no sense. I have to wonder if this is the result of your quotation.

First of all, the processor does not block processes; the operating system does.

Second, I have not worked on an operating system that works anything like the way you describe here.

Usually, if a disk drive triggers an interrupt, the current process handles that interrupt. While in kernel mode the operating system does whatever queuing is necessary for the disk operation. If the process's time slice is up, only then does the process change. If not, after interrupt handling, the process picks up where it left off before the interrupt.

I cannot imagine a "modern" operating system that invokes a disk process to handle disk interrupts.